# Minimum sum weight of connecting 3 vertices in an undirected, weighted graph, with only positive edge weights

Tags: algorithm, graph, computer-science

I'm looking for pointers as to where one could start looking for a solution to this problem.

After googling for some time, the only problem I have found which is simmilar to my problem is a [minimum spanning tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree). The difference is that I am not looking for a tree that spans all the vertices in a graph, rather who spans 3 given vertices.

I am not looking for a complete program, but a pointer in the general direction of the answer.

Another idea I had was to run 3 searches with the [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm). The idea was to somehow find the best path by combining the different shortest paths. I do not know how this would be done.

Here is a graphical example of the type of graph I am talking about:

[image]

So the task is to find an way to find the minimum sum weight of connecting any 3 vertecies in this kind of graph.

**EDIT :**
I solved the problem by running 3 searches with Dijkstra's algorithem. Then I found the vertex which had the minimum sum weight connecting the 3 vertexes by adding togheter all uniqe edges. Thanks for all the help :)

Comment: *The title really says it all*. No, not really. This is not a write-code-for-me site. Please show what you have tried.

Comment: "I am going to provide an example graphic as fast as I can." - couldn't you wait until you had said graphic **before** posting the question?

Comment: @Dukeling Many of the other questions I have seen on SO regarding graphs has been resolved without the use of a image. I thought posting the question now would reveale if this question is easy to answer or require more explanation on my part.

Comment: With the clarification, the question is a lot easier to understand. This question and most of those questions probably would've been a little / a lot better with an example, including an image and explanation, added. If it takes you more than 10 minutes to make an example image, you're doing something wrong. If you're not willing to spend at the very least 10 minutes on a question (for the first draft), you should seriously reconsider asking a question on [so].

Comment: Please be courteous and select an answer, other people have suggested the same solution that you finally ended up with (although, it's worth noting, it's not optimal, you don't need to try every unique combination of edges you need only discard the longest one).

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can do this with Dijkstra's algorithm, the only trick is you don't know what order to visit the nodes in, so you'd have to try all 6 orderings.

So if you've got nodes A, B, and C, for the first ordering A, B, C, you'd run Dijkstra's between A and B, between B and C, and between C and A. Then you'd do the next ordering A, C, B. And keep going from there.

Comment: I don't think this works for a graph A,B,C,D where D connects to all vertices with weight 3, and all other edges are weight 5.  Connecting A,B,C in the smallest way involves using D for a total cost of 9, but the individual shortest paths do not go via D.

Comment: Yep, you're right. I don't think yours works either though. Your algorithm double-counts edges that are shared in shortest paths from the test node to each goal node.

Comment: I think you can make your version work by setting edge weights to zero if they've already been used when running Dijkstra for the second and third nodes.

Answer (score 0):

### Algorithm 1

I think that your idea of using Dijkstra is good.

One way in which you could make this work is by trying every vertex x as a start point and compute the smallest value for the sum w(x,a)+w(x,b)+w(x,c) where a,b,c are the 3 vertices you wish to connect and w(u,v) is the shortest path computed with Dijkstra.

I believe this smallest sum will be the minimum sum weight to connect the 3 vertices.

Unfortunately, this means running Djikstra 3.n times.

### Algorithm 2

A better approach is to run Djikstra from each of your nodes to be connected, and store the distances to each node in your graph.  (So wa(x) is the shortest distance from x to a, etc.)

You can then iterate over every vertex x as before and compute the smallest value for the sum wa(x)+wb(x)+wc(x)

This is equivalent to algorithm 1, but n times faster as Dijkstra is only run 3 times.

Comment: A disclaimer about negative edge weights should perhaps be added (the question doesn't specify that there are only positive edge weights). Also, "Algorithm 1" and "Algorithm 2" should probably be renamed to something more explanatory.

Comment: I was actually thinking about version number 1. But Version number 2 seems very interesting as well :) I will try it out on paper and see if it turns out alright :D

Comment: After having tried you algorithm, I found a flaw. It counts edges multiple times if the path between wa(x) and wb(x) shares any edges.

Comment: Are you trying all values of x?  If the path between a->x and b->x share an edge, then if you move x along this path you can reduce the total cost.  In other words, for the optimal value of x I believe that the path a->x and b->x will never share any edges.

Answer (score 0):

With the restrictions that the weights are all positive and the graph is undirected, you can solve the problem using Dijkstra's algorithm, as suggested, let us say that the nodes in question are `A`, `B`, `C`, all in some graph `G`.

- Run Dijkstra's on `G` from:

  - `A -> B`
  - `B -> C`
  - `C -> A`
- These form the edges of a triangle connecting the three vertices.

  We can do this because of the condition that the graph is undirected which implies that the shortest path from `A -> B` is the same as the one from `B -> A`.
- Because the weights are all positive, the shortest path connecting `A`, `B`, and `C` will contain precisely two edges. (Assuming you are happy ignoring the possible alternate solution of a cycle arising from three 0 weight paths in the "triangle").
- So how do we pick which two edges? Any two edges will connect all three vertices, so we can eliminate any of the three, so we will eliminate the longest one.

So this algorithm will do it in the same time complexity as Dijkstra's algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [generalization of minimum Steiner tree problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_tree#Generalization_of_minimum_Steiner_tree).

Comment: As I understand it, this is more like a [minimum spanning tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree) than a minimum Steiner tree, because we aren't allowed to add edges or vertecies.

Comment: First problem described in a chapter (Steiner tree in graphs) is on general graphs, so without adding edges or vertices.